# Find records with Many2Many using activeJDBC

Tags: many-to-many, activejdbc, javalite

I have these annotations for the models:

```
@Many2Many(other = Course.class, join = "registrations", sourceFKName = "student_uid", targetFKName = "course_uid")
public class Student extends Model {
}

@Many2Many(other = Student.class, join = "registrations", sourceFKName = "course_uid", targetFKName = "student_uid")
public class Course extends Model {
}
```

How do I get all Students belong to a course UID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need to specify the same annotation twice. This will work just the same:

```
public class Student extends Model {}

@Many2Many(other = Student.class, join = "registrations", sourceFKName = "course_uid", targetFKName = "student_uid")
public class Course extends Model { }
```

Second, your case is described on this page: http://javalite.io/many_to_many_associations#select-related-objects

so, you would:

```
Course course = Course.findById(id);
List<Student> students = course.getAll(Student.class);
```

That is all!